# Using two routers to extend ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

I currently have two routers set up at home. Essentially the ethernet cable from the first router is connected to my second router, which has different network credentials.

I've used the second router's ethernet port to extend the ethernet to my PC, since the ethernet port can't reach directly to my PC from the first router.

Are there any settings or tweaks I could perform to reduce ping and latency from my ethernet connection to my second router.

I don't have any special settings enabled. I just made a new network on my second router and use that for my upstairs and the one downstairs for my downstairs wifi.

I appreciate all of the help!

Comment: @John That will make absolutely no difference to ping or latency ...

Comment: @john Upgrading firmware is also unlikely to make any difference ...